# Strike effect in Tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was working on a Tic Tac Toe game and was trying to make a strike effect for the Winner's squares.

My idea was, I could take first and last squash, get their mid position and use a canvas to create a line but its not working properly.

Following is a sample code with [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/qkpyc29n/53/):

```js
function TicTacToe(container) {
  let count = 0;
  const getLabel = () => count++ % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'Y';

  function createGrid() {
    const handlerFn = function() {
      this.innerText = getLabel();
      this.removeEventListener('click', handlerFn);
    }
    Array.from({
      length: 9
    }, (_, i) => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('tile')
      div.addEventListener('click', handlerFn)
      container.append(div);
    });
  }
  
  function createStrikeLine() {
    const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');
    const [ startX, startY ] = getPosition(tiles[0]);
    const [ endX, endY ] = getPosition(tiles[8]);
    
    console.log(startX, startY, endX, endY)
    
    const canvas = document.getElementById('ctx-strike');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(startX, startY);
    context.lineTo(endX, endY);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }
  
  function getPosition(element) {
   const left = element.offsetLeft;
    const top = element.offsetTop;
    const height = Math.floor(element.offsetWidth / 2);
    return [ left + height, top + height ];
  }

  createGrid();
  createStrikeLine();
}

const containerDiv = document.querySelector('.content');
TicTacToe(containerDiv)
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 30vmax;
}

#ctx-strike {
  /* position: absolute; */
  height: 30vmax;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tile {
  margin: 2px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.strike-through {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 21vmax;
  
}
.translate-45 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <canvas id='ctx-strike'></canvas>
</div>
```

Now I understand, issue is with co-ordinates, but I tried to make the canvas full with, still it fails. So the question,

- How to determine correct co-ordinates for any tile?
- Is there a better way to make stike effect other than canvas?

Another issue i saw was, entire UI is responsive but not the canvas. If you resize container, tiles expand/shrink but the line remains same

Answer (score 0):

Post the last update:

> Another issue i saw was, entire UI is responsive but not the canvas. If you resize container, tiles expand/shrink but the line remains same

I thought of using `div` and css instead of `canvas`. Yes, canvas would have been less work, css is able to handle responsiveness a bit.

#### Idea:

I created 8 classes with possible patterns for strike through:

- Row-wise: Players can win in 3 pattern if they choose same value in either of rows.
- Column-wise: Players can win in 3 pattern if they choose same value in either of column.
- Diagonals: They can choose in either diagonal way.

Now in my validation logic, all I have to do is decide if there is a win, choose win pattern and pass it to my function.

**[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9Lbu6hxm/26/)**

Note: I added dropdown so users can play and check these patterns individually.

```js
function TicTacToe(container) {
  const strikePatterns = [
    'row-1', 'row-2', 'row-3',
    'col-1', 'col-2', 'col-3',
    'dig-1', 'dig-2'
  ];
  let count = 0;
  const getLabel = () => count++ % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'Y';

  function createGrid() {
    const handlerFn = function() {
      this.innerText = getLabel();
      this.removeEventListener('click', handlerFn);
    }
    Array.from({
      length: 9
    }, (_, i) => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('tile')
      div.addEventListener('click', handlerFn)
      container.append(div);
    });
  }

  function createStrikeLine(patternName) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('strike-through');

    div.classList.add(patternName)
    container.append(div);
  }
  
  createGrid();

  function createPatternSelect(value) {
    const select = document.createElement('select');
    strikePatterns.forEach(function(pattern) {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.innerText = pattern;
      option.value = pattern;
      select.append(option);
    })
    if (value) {
      select.value = value;
    }
    select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      container.innerHTML = '';
      createGrid();
      createPatternSelect(this.value);
      createStrikeLine(this.value);
    })
    container.append(select)
  }
  createPatternSelect();
}

const containerDiv = document.querySelector('.content');
TicTacToe(containerDiv)
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 30vmax;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ctx-strike {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tile {
  margin: 2px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.strike-through {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 1px;
}

.row-1 {
  margin-top: -10vw;
}

.row-2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.row-3 {
  margin-top: 8vw;
}

.col-1 {
  margin-left: -9vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.col-2 {
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.col-3 {
  margin-left: 9vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.dig-1 {
  margin-top: -1vw;
  width: 27vw;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.dig-2 {
  margin-top: -1vw;
  width: 27vw;
  
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Note:** Not marking this as answer as there can be better ways to handle this. If you have any idea/ solution, feel free to answer/ comment with it. Any pointers will also be appreciated.